# Nested WHILE loop in SQL runs the inner loop, but does not run the outer loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, while-loop

I create a procedure to consolidate all info calculated per each **X** & **Y** value combinations. I use a simple indexing to fetch the values of **X** & **Y** by using 2-step `WHILE` loops.

Here are the **X** & **Y**  support tables:

[image: X & Y]

However, the result is below as `[MAIN_TABLE]`. **However, I expect it to be the all combinations of **X** & **Y**.**

[image: Result]

Here is my code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CONSOLIDATION_Procedure]     
AS
BEGIN
    
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.[MAIN_TABLE]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
         DELETE FROM [MAIN_TABLE]
    
    DECLARE @IndexX INT SET @IndexX=1
    DECLARE @IndexY INT SET @IndexY=1
    DECLARE @IndexX_Max INT SET @IndexX_Max = (SELECT MAX([Index]) FROM [temp_X_Index])
    DECLARE @IndexY_Max INT SET @IndexY_Max = (SELECT MAX([Index]) FROM [temp_Y_Index])
    
    WHILE @IndexX <= @IndexX_Max 
    BEGIN         
        DECLARE @XVal VARCHAR(20) SET @XVal = (SELECT [X_VAL] FROM [temp_X_Index] WHERE [INDEX]=@IndexX)
    
        WHILE @IndexY <= @IndexY_Max 
        BEGIN         
            DECLARE @YVAL VARCHAR(20) SET @YVAL = (SELECT [Y_VAL] FROM [temp_Y_Index] WHERE [INDEX]=@IndexY)            
            INSERT INTO [MAIN_TABLE]        
                SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SUPPORT_TABLE] WHERE [X] = @XVal AND [Y]= @YVAL
        
        SET @IndexY = @IndexY+1
        END
    
    SET @IndexX = @IndexX+1
    END
    
  END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `Cartesian product`(cross join) instead of this block code to generate it.

```
SELECT x.[index] x_index, y.[index] as y_index, x_val, y_val
  FROM [temp_X_Index] x
 CROSS JOIN [temp_Y_Index] y
```

Comment: Can also use cross join to mean the same thing (bit more explicit)

Comment: Specifically I think @tinazmu means use this syntax `FROM X CROSS JOIN Y` it makes the meaning a little more obvious

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  and tinazmu I update to with that keyword

Comment: You mean, use one `WHILE` and refer to the cross-joined table? - @FarshidShekari

Comment: @BTurkeli no a while loop is unnecssary. Try it and see.

Comment: @BTurkeli  I mean this code will do all you need to do.

Comment: @BTurkeli it is *very* rare you ever need a `WHILE` loop in SQL. SQL is a set-based language, and so it excels at set-based operations; a `WHILE` is the *opposite* to that methodology. If you are considering using a `WHILE` when writing SQL, you are very likely making the wrong decisions.